# C# - How to pass/skip over data in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a project for my programming and problem solving class and this particular program is suppose to read census data from a text file (notepad) and then display the the number of residents in each age group as well as the number of residents in each district.

**From assignment:**

*The fields in each record will be separated by a comma.*

**For example:** 21, M, S, 1

*"The city has 22 districts. The census department wants to see a listing of how many residents are in each district, and a count of residents in each of the following age groups (for all the districts combined): under 18, 18 through 30, 31 through 45, 46 through 64, and 65 or older."*

I have a text file to test and everything seems to work however, if I use a character instead of a number (like "a" or "B") it breaks my program. How can I tell the program to skip the data if the data is not an number or I guess"int" value? I assume some kind of try.Parse, however I have only ever seen it demonstrated via console input, not from an array...

My code is below. Thank you for your help. I appreciate all criticism and advice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Project2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        int[] ageData = new int[900];
        int[] districtDataA = new int[900];
        int[] ageGroup = new int[5];
        int[] districtCount = new int[22];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"))
        {
            string[] fields = line.Split(',');

            ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);          
            districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(fields[3]);


            if (ageData[i] > 0 && ageData[i] <= 18)
            {
                ageGroup[0] = ageGroup[0] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 18 && ageData[i] <= 30)
            {
                ageGroup[1] = ageGroup[1] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 30 && ageData[i] <= 45)
            {
                ageGroup[2] = ageGroup[2] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 45 && ageData[i] <= 64)
            {
                ageGroup[3] = ageGroup[3] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] >= 65)
            {
                ageGroup[4] = ageGroup[4] + 1;
            }

            //District Count info
            if (districtDataA[i] == 1)
            {
                districtCount[0] = districtCount[0] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 2)
            {
                districtCount[1] = districtCount[1] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 3)
            {
                districtCount[2] = districtCount[2] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 4)
            {
                districtCount[3] = districtCount[3] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 5)
            {
                districtCount[4] = districtCount[4] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 6)
            {
                districtCount[5] = districtCount[5] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 7)
            {
                districtCount[6] = districtCount[6] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 8)
            {
                districtCount[7] = districtCount[7] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 9)
            {
                districtCount[8] = districtCount[8] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 10)
            {
                districtCount[9] = districtCount[9] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 11)
            {
                districtCount[10] = districtCount[10] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 12)
            {
                districtCount[11] = districtCount[11] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 13)
            {
                districtCount[12] = districtCount[12] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 14)
            {
                districtCount[13] = districtCount[13] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 15)
            {
                districtCount[14] = districtCount[14] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 16)
            {
                districtCount[15] = districtCount[15] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 17)
            {
                districtCount[16] = districtCount[16] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 18)
            {
                districtCount[17] = districtCount[17] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 19)
            {
                districtCount[18] = districtCount[18] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 20)
            {
                districtCount[19] = districtCount[19] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 21)
            {
                districtCount[20] = districtCount[20] + 1;
            }
            if (districtDataA[i] == 22)
            {
                districtCount[21] = districtCount[21] + 1;
            }

            i++;

        }//End For

        Console.WriteLine("This program provides a list of residents in 5 age groups,");
        Console.WriteLine("And a list of residents in each district 1-22");
        Console.WriteLine("(1.)----------------AGE-GROUP-Count----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 18 & under = {0}", ageGroup[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 18-30 = {0}", ageGroup[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 31-45 = {0}", ageGroup[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 46-64 = {0}", ageGroup[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 65 & over = {0}", ageGroup[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("(2.)--------------COUNT-PER-DISRTRICT--------------");
        Console.WriteLine("District 1 = {0}", districtCount[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 2 = {0}", districtCount[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 3 = {0}", districtCount[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 4 = {0}", districtCount[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 5 = {0}", districtCount[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 6 = {0}", districtCount[5]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 7 = {0}", districtCount[6]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 8 = {0}", districtCount[7]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 9 = {0}", districtCount[8]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 10 = {0}", districtCount[9]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 11 = {0}", districtCount[10]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 12 = {0}", districtCount[11]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 13 = {0}", districtCount[12]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 14 = {0}", districtCount[13]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 15 = {0}", districtCount[14]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 16 = {0}", districtCount[15]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 17 = {0}", districtCount[16]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 18 = {0}", districtCount[17]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 19 = {0}", districtCount[18]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 20 = {0}", districtCount[19]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 21 = {0}", districtCount[20]);
        Console.WriteLine("District 22 = {0}", districtCount[21]);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Off-topic (assuming you code is working and you have no problem to ask about). Possibly ok on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes it reads all the values that are "int", but when putting a char value in where my age value should be in the text file, it breaks it. My teachers tells us to prepare for anything, so I know he will run a text file with incorrect formatting (such as the char "a") that will break it, and i don't want him to break it.

Comment: I apologize, I did not know about the codereview section. That does seem like the best place. I will make sure in the future to use that for similar questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
double n;
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"))
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        bool ageIsNumeric = double.TryParse(fields[0], out n);
        bool districtIsNumeric = double.TryParse(fields[3], out n);
        if(!ageIsNumeric || !districtIsNumeric)
            continue;
        ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);          
        districtDataA[i] = int.Parse(fields[3]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this prevented my program from breaking due to incorrect formatting!

Answer (score 0):

you read a data from the txt file as a string 
insert your code inside the foreach statement inside  try catch block

```
    foreach()
{

try{
//your code here

}catch(Exception){}
}
```